# how to delete an entire row in excel 2013 if one of the cells in the same row is deleted?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Can you suggest any methods wherein whenever I delete a data in a specific cell all of the other data along its row will automatically be deleted?

I have already researched doing so and I have came up with using Visual Basics for Application code delete blank rows 2 but I do not really know how to use it. Can anyone teach me how to use the code I mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not have a VBA event for a cell delete.

You can use a Worksheet_Change event. This event will be triggered whenever a cell in the sheet is changed. If, after the change, the cell is blank, it stands to reason whether or not the user has just deleted a cell or hit enter upon editing a cell that was already blank, without writing anything into the cell.

The change event could be set up to monitor only a specific range, say, columns A to F, and will only delete the row if a cell in these columns is empty after a change.

With this as a pre-amble, here is some code that does what I describe.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:F")) Is Nothing Then
    If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Cell was deleted - now deleting row" ' remove this line if you dont want the message
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' turn off event monitoring so the routine does not loop
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' turn on event monitoring
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Copy this code. Then right-click the sheet tab, select "View Code" in the context menu and paste the code into the code window.  Remember to save the file as a macro-enabled .xlsm file.